# When “Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected” is enabled, when does sync happen?

Tags: macos, iphone, data-synchronization

I can trigger sync on macOS in Finder, but how often does it sync? Can I trigger a sync using command line or on iPhone?

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I think I read somewhere 15 mins, but I also read somewhere about backups that only run when the screen is locked and only once a day ..

Comment: I always thought it synced once, at connect - but I've had this switched off for years, because mainly I just want to charge it, or grab a photo when I connect, so everything is set to manual.